# Can two different subspaces of R^n have the same orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't think of an instance that would show otherwise

Thank you

Comment: No, because $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$

Answer (score 1):

No. If $A^{\perp}=B^{\perp}$ then $A=B$ because $A=(A^{\perp})^{\perp}$ and $B=(B^{\perp})^{\perp}$ . More generally in Hilbert spaces $A^{\perp}=B^{\perp}$ implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same closure. In finite dimensions all subspaces are closed.